# Sending arguments to Java requests in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have two questions,

1. How can I send arguments to Java requests in Jmeter
2. How to capture the SampleResult from one JavaRequest and pass it to Other Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the [Java Request Sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)
2. Use the post-processor [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)